# Solana Flutter create transaction for phantom /signAndSendTransaction deeplink

Tags: transactions, phantom, flutter, deeplink

I want to fund another user's wallet (let's say I have their public wallet address in my code) from my phantom wallet using a Flutter app.

Now I can use the `/connect` deeplink of Phantom in a Flutter app, but how do I create a transaction for transferring funds to another wallet in Flutter and then execute it through Phantom's `/signAndSendTransaction`? I know I need to use the Cryptoplease package, but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my package for flutter [flutter_phantom](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phantom)

```
    Future<web3.Transaction> createTransactionTransfer() async {
  final transaction = web3.Transaction(
      feePayer: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
      recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash);
  transaction.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer(
      fromPublicKey: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
      toPublicKey: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
      lamports: web3.solToLamports(1),
    ),
  );
  return transaction;
}

 void signAndSendTransaction() async {
  try { 
    web3.Transaction transaction = await createTransactionTransfer();

    web3.Buffer transactionSerialize = transaction
        .serialize(const web3.SerializeConfig(requireAllSignatures: false));

    final url = phantom.generateSignAndSendTransactionUri(
        transaction: transactionSerialize,
        redirect: "onSignAndSendTransaction");
  
    launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
    );
  } catch (e) {
  print(e)
  }
}
```

full example of how to use this package (Android,Ios) [flutter_phantom-demo](https://github.com/NavidHosseini/flutter_phantom-demo).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following the [merigolabs's](https://pub.dev/packages/solana_web3) Solana DART API.

Here's an example how to create a transaction to transfer SOL from 1 wallet to another.

```
// Create a System Program instruction to transfer 1 SOL from [address1] to [address2].
final transaction = web3.Transaction();
transaction.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer(
        fromPublicKey: address1, 
        toPublicKey: address2, 
        lamports: web3.solToLamports(1),
    ),
);
```

You will additionally have to [serialise](https://pub.dev/documentation/solana_web3/latest/solana_web3/Transaction/serialize.html) this transaction and provide it as payload to the Phantom deeplink as a parameter, as mentioned [here](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/deeplinks-ios-and-android/provider-methods/signandsendtransaction#query-string-parameters).

Hope this helps.